# How to use both linked ledger and fundraiser wallet with tezbox?

Tags: ledger, tezbox

I need to send my XTZ from my fundraiser wallet to a tezbox wallet linked with my ledger nano.

I began by the "create tezbox" method which allowed me to access my fundraiser funds and send some XTZ.

Next I tried to use the "link tezbox" method to create another account based on my ledger nano S where i wish to send my XTZ.

But the windows client seems to allow only one method, because the landing screen with both methods "create" and "link" appears only when there is no tezbox wallet yet.

So, what am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tezbox currently only allows you to view/manage one set of keys at a time. In your case either your fundraiser ICO keys or your ledger keys.

Until they add the ability to view multiple wallets/keys, you need to use another wallet software for your 2nd set of keys. If you want to stick with Tezbox only, you can use it in a different browser or use the Tezbox desktop client.